# Casting UIWindow.rootView to UIHostingController<View> which has environment variables

Tags: swiftui, rootview, environmentobject, uihostingcontroller

Casting UIWindow.rootView to a hosting controller like:

```swift
window?.rootViewController as? UIHostingController<MainTabView>
```

works fine, unless it has `environmentObject`s.

As my `MainTabView` has been initialized with `.environmentObject`, I cannot cast it to `UIHostingController<MainTabView>`.

When I try to print `rootView`'s type, Xcode tells:

```sh
<_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentGS1_V10Panparella11MainTabViewGVS_30_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifierGSqCS2_11GroupsStore___GS4_GSqCS2_18GroupsPresentation____: 0x7fd8afe5da40>
```

which I suppose is:

```sh
UIHostingController<ModifiedContent<MainTabView, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<GroupsStore, GroupsPresentation>>>
```

but I'm not able to reach `_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier`.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: What gives you casting to `UIHostingController<MainTabView>`? ... anyway, just wrap it in your custom view controller w/o generics... bug casting is bad... very bad. ;)

Comment: it's nil when casted to `UIHostingController<MainTabView>` and I can't wrap it without giving UIHostingController's rootView type. As it's not my custom view controller, it doesn't seem possible to reach its view without casting it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one EnvironmentObject the following typecast compiles and works fine.

```
UIHostingController<ModifiedContent<MainTabView, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<GroupStore>>>>
```

Even though this is not a complete answer to the question (since there are multiple EnvironmentObjects) I am posting it here in case it might help someone that uses a single EnvironmentObject.